# Django - list of logged in user's posts

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

there is a blog project. its working correctly now. there will be multiple users.

i want to list posts which are created by user that logged in right now. if 'x' user log in , he must see just his own posts on **admin page**.

what is the correct way for this ?

here is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',unique=True)
    posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    isdraft = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title()

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_post',None, {'postslug':self.slug})


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

def create_user(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user, sender=User)
```

and my views.py ( just part of admin page ) :

```
@login_required(login_url='/panel/')
def adminView(request):
    if request.session['loggedin']=="djangoo":

        draft_list = Post.objects.filter(isdraft=True).order_by("-posted")
        p_draft = Paginator(draft_list,15)

        publish_list = Post.objects.filter(isdraft=False).order_by("-posted")
        p_publish = Paginator(publish_list,15)

        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            post_d = p_draft.page(page)
            post_p = p_publish.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            post_d = p_draft.page(1)
            post_p = p_publish.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            post_d = p_draft.page(p_draft.num_pages)
            post_p = p_publish.page(p_publish.num_pages)


        return render_to_response('admin.html',
                                  {'draft_list':draft_list,'publish_list':publish_list,'post_d':post_d,'post_p':post_p},
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        HttpResponseRedirect('/panel/')
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store user which posted it in your post model and then you can easily filter out those.

I would update model like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User')
    # your other fields
```

And admin view :

```
@login_required(login_url='/panel/')
def adminView(request):
    draft_list = Post.objects.filter(owner=request.user).filter(isdraft=True).order_by("-posted")
    #------------------------------^^^^ filter based on owner
    p_draft = Paginator(draft_list,15)

    publish_list = Post.objects.filter(owner=request.user).filter(isdraft=False).order_by("-posted")
    p_publish = Paginator(publish_list,15)
    #your other view code
    ...
```

Also, you will have to update the view which adds a post to put `owner` as well.

Comment: @drTerminal, Have you resynced DB? Note you will have to reset the DB as `syncdb` will not add the new column. Also, have you set `owner` attribute when you added a post?

Comment: i fixed it. it s about a database error. i recreated the db and now it is working fine :)